# Get shape of route link

Tags: here-api

Is there a possibility to get a shape, either polyline or coordinates, of route link by it's id using HERE API? I am calculating a road using calculate route endpoint by passing few avoid link's which I would like to show on the map. How can I achieve that? I was able to get tileX and tileY for each link using https://pde.cit.api.here.com/1/index.json but when I convert it to coordinates(per documentation) it gives me inaccurate results.

Comment: Can you share a bit more details in this? Maybe an example within such an inaccurate result?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using REST API, you can get shape with a request like this:

```
http://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?
app_id=XXXX
&app_code=YYYYY
&mode=fastest;car
&routeattributes=shape
&waypoint0=48.98381310475713,2.5028838962316513
&waypoint1=48.83000339882299,2.2315230274810745
```